# Parsing a signal emitted List containing list inside a PyQt5 Tableview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a script that returns data in a dict format inside a list. So my list ***data[]*** contains the following data

```
[['https://www.impasd.com.au/', 'https://www.impasd.com.au/who-we-are/'],['697559', '459048'], ['Full Service', 'Agency Partner']]
```

I would like to display this data inside a Table in the PyQt5 TableView that I have defined as folow. The data updates live so I had like to continue to update the table as the data updates.

Now I have a PyQt5 windows that looks like below. The big white section is defined as a TabelView [image]

My main PyQt5 code is main.py

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1327, 901)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1331, 851))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

data = [['https://www.impasd.com.au/', 'https://www.impasd.com.au/who-we-are/'], ['697559', '459048'], ['Full Service', 'Agency Partner']]

        self.model = TableModel( data )
        self.table.setModel( self.model )

        self.setCentralWidget( self.table )

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the process runs my data is available within the main class where I have also defined a Model

```py
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        print(self._data)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])
```

And no Table is displayed. What could I be doing wrong ?

----UPDATE----

I have now converted my results[] into a list of lists so the question has changed slightly. "Parsing a signal emitted List containing **LIST** inside a PyQt5 Tableview"

I have also made some progress in the last few hours so the window triggers and I get no error and the program finishes with exit code 0 , yet the table is empty ?

Comment: There's no trace of `self._values` in your code. Please provide a fully [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hey @musicamante, For the sake of reproducing I have now hard coded the data list. If you chuck the entire code into a main.py and add the tablemodel at the top of the main.py the program should run without errors and no table, just blank screen.

Comment: I don't know if you're trying to edit the code generated from `pyuic` or you're trying to mimick its behavior, but in either cases you should *never* do that (and that's the reason for which you're not seeing anything). Read the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) and you'll see that, if you follow them carefully, your code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining two different instances of `QMainWindow` namely `MainWindow` and `ui`. Each of these has a `QTableView` set as their central widget but you only set a model for one of them namely `ui.centralWidget()`. However, the window that is shown is the other one: `MainWindow`, which doesn't have a model set for its table view.

Since you appear to have been editing a .py file which was generated from Qt Designer + pyuic, I would suggest that you regenerate the .py from pyuic and instead of editing it directly (which is always a bad idea) create a separate .py file where you define a class which inherits from both `QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow` to setup your main window. So, assuming that `Ui_MainWindow.py` is the output file of Qt Designer, you would create a different .py file and do something like this

```
import QtWidgets, QtCore
import Ui_MainWindow, TableModel

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        data = [['https://www.impasd.com.au/', 'https://www.impasd.com.au/who-we-are/'], 
                ['697559', '459048'], ['Full Service', 'Agency Partner']]
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Ahh ! That solved it. So, you are suggesting never to edit the file generated from pyuic + designer conversion ? I think I get the point that I can always create a new class and inherit from it. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question.